# Why won't the appSettings file attribute allow a path to the parent directory?

Tags: c#, configuration-files, appsettings

I'm trying to deploy a project with multiple executables, some of which use a common config file. I'd like to have this common config file in its own directory. The problem is that it keeps getting ignored. I have the tag:

```
<appSettings file="..\Common Configs\Common.config">
```

in some of the executable-specific config files. If I copy the Common.config file to the same directory as the specific config file, and remove the path from the tag, everything works. It even works if I do something like:

```
<appSettings file="..\App1\Common.config">
```

where `App1` is the folder the executable lives in.

[This page](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/93626/configsource-attribute-on-config-sections-doesnt-support-parent-or-absolute-config-paths) suggests that the `ConfigSource` doesn't allow paths to the parent, but the `file` attribute does.

To further complicate matters, I'm deploying to a file share, so I can't create hard links in the exe folders.

Does anyone know why this doesn't work? How else can I deploy this with a shared config file?

The folder structure has the following form:

Solution

- Common Configs

  - Common.config
- App1

  - App1.exe
  - App1.exe.config
- App2

  - App2.exe
  - App2.exe.config

Comment: Can you post your complete folder structure?

Comment: Does it work if the config file is directly in the parent directory (rather than a different sub-directory)?

Comment: It certainly seems to work when all files are local - so maybe the file share aspect is the important one. (Just tried it under .NET 4.5RC, Console Application)

Comment: It doesn't work if the config file is directly in the parent directory. Strangely, it does work if I copy `Common.config` to the App1 folder and write `<appSettings file="..\App1\Common.config">` in `App1.exe.config` (step up to parent directory and navigate back down again).

Answer (score 1):

If all of the projects are in the same solution, you can add the configuration file to the Solution Items area. This file can then be shared with all of the exes within the solution.

You will need to select each project that needs the configuration file and choose to Add Existing Item. From there, choose the file, then Add as Link.

This will allow you to maintain the one configuration file and have it deployed side by side with each exe.

Then when you reference it via the appSettings section, you can just reference the file directly.

Comment: That's useful during development, and I'm doing something similar. My problem is that once it's deployed I only want one copy of the common config.